# ext: jh_magnificpopup: problems when overwriting template paths etc

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm running typo3 7.6.10 and jh_magnificpopup 0.6.4

I'm not able to change sucessfully the template root path.
`plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view.templateRootPath`

also I'm not able to remove the inline js generated by the extension.

this is really strange.

Comment: It is hard to help if you don't tell us which TS you are using.

Comment: i only edit in the constant editor of jh_magnificpopup this:

plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view.partialRootPath = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Private/Partials/



plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view.templateRootPath = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Private/Templates/ 


then nothing happens, although i changed the templates and partials.

strange is, that when i type in a wrong path, there comes the error mesage: template not found. this seems to be correct

Comment: i only edit in the constant editor of jh_magnificpopup this:  
    `plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view.partialRootPath = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Pr‌iv​ate/Partials/ `
`plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view.templateRootPath = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Pr‌​ivate/Templates/`
then nothing happens, although i changed the templates and partials. strange is, that when i type in a wrong path, there comes the error mesage: template not found. this seems to be correct

Comment: @MarkusDübbert Please [edit] your question with the additional information instead of posting comments, they are extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template path using the below typoscript.

Add this in Setup of your root page' system template :

```
plugin.tx_jhmagnificpopup.view {
    partialRootPaths.10 = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Pr‌​‌iv​ate/Partials/
    templateRootPaths.10 = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Pr‌​‌iv​ate/Templates/
    layoutRootPaths.10 = fileadmin/Resources/Extensions/jh_magnificpopup/Resources/Pr‌​‌iv​ate/Layouts/
}
```